# post_delete is not called

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Django 1.11.7
Python 3.6.5

I tried to implement following code to delete a file when a model is deleted.
But post_delete is not called.

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=HogeFileModel, dispatch_uid=uuid.uuid4())
@receiver(post_delete, sender=FugaFileModel, dispatch_uid=uuid.uuid4())
def auto_delete_file_on_delete_part_file(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    print('Called post_delete')
    if instance.file:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.file.path):
            os.remove(instance.file.path)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: How do you know it's not called?

Comment: @Lemayzeur If printed 'Called post_delete' when call HogeFileModel.objects.get(pk=~~).delete()

Comment: did you try with `pre_delete()` and why adding the decorator twice?

Comment: @Lemayzeur just it tried, but it was not called><   why adding the decorator twice? >> My server program has some models that are similar. So I added the decorator twice or more time.

Comment: is it in a separate file like signals.py?

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy No. it is in models.py(which declares Model)